# Codehs and KhanAcademy different use of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

At my school I am learning how to code in JS using a site called codehs.com. After a while I learned about graphics with JS. There was this one point where I had to create a circle:

```
var circle = new Circle(50);
circle.setPosition(100,100);
add(circle);
```

After a few days I came across another website that was teaching students how code using JS. The website was called khanacademy.org I was interested and saw that the first lesson was making drawings. I looked at the video provided and it had a different code to make a circle.

```
ellipse(203, 197, 300, 350);
```

I am confused on how to make a circle  using JS since I just started.

Comment: "Creating circles" is not something that JavaScript, the language, supports out of the box (at least it doesn't provide a specialized API for that). So there are *libraries* that provide specialized APIs and of course there can be multiple libraries that provide the same functionality. These two sites seem to use different libraries. What specific library you use shouldn't matter for learning the *language*.

Comment: There are many libraries to do alot of things. Libraries are created to make things easier, rather than using "pure" javascript. The reason for that is, doign something simple (Like perhaps animation, if you don't use css) can take long amounts of code. Instead there are libraries that have keywords that do these long amounts of code behind the scenes, so you don't have to waste an hour coding a trivial animation on your website. That being said, everything you do can be done with pure javascript. The reality is, I'm lazy as hell, I rather use libraries to do things that take alot of time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the founders of CodeHS. CodeHS uses a custom JavaScript library on top of regular JavaScript. Khan Academy uses Processing JS, which is a different library (You can use Processing on CodeHS as well if you like).

You can see the documentation for everything in the CodeHS JS library at https://codehs.com/docs and learn how to use it in the [Intro CS in JavaScript](https://codehs.com/info/curriculum/introjs) course.

We have designed this library to be great for learning -- it gives you experience using Object Oriented Programming while making it simple to create and manipulate shapes for programs like a [Helicopter Game](https://codehs.com/demos/helicopter).

Additionally, you can include the library on an HTML page that runs JavaScript by adding this script tag to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.codehs.com/gulp/3d065bc81d3b7edf21e928ce2c764374a03c5cd6/chs-js-lib/chs.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of a full HTML page that runs JavaScript and uses the CodeHS library on it to draw a circle.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Circle Example</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.codehs.com/gulp/3d065bc81d3b7edf21e928ce2c764374a03c5cd6/chs-js-lib/chs.js"></script>


<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Circle Example</h1>



<canvas
width="400"
height="500"
class="codehs-editor-canvas"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var circle = new Circle(50);
    circle.setPosition(100,100);
    add(circle);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thanks. No offense but for me it's pretty hard to believe that you are the co-founder of codehs.com. The reason for this is because anyone can make a name like yours and use the same picture, but I will take your word for it. Thanks for telling me the difference.

Comment: Haha yeah, I guess someone could do that, but it is actually me. If you want, you can email zach@codehs.com and I'll be happy to reply saying it was me :)

Comment: It's ok I will take your word for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like KHAN ACADEMY uses [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/reference/ellipse_/) to draw the circle

[image: KHAN ACADEMY]

I was unable to check what is the library CodeHS uses to draw a circle, but has to be a different one. But the fact is that there are so many good libraries developed in javascript to make whatever you can imagine. They're generally different one from another but their goal is to make our life easier.

[JavaScript library | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_library)

[What's a JS library? | KHAN ACADEMY](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css-js/using-js-libraries-in-your-webpage/a/whats-a-js-library)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the processing platform for CodeHs, just copying and pasting this code:

```
/**
 * This program finds the shortest path through a series of obstacles using A* search,
 * smooths the path, then uses PID control to drive a robot to the goal.
 **/

// You can play around with these constants---
var NUM_BLOCKS = 20;
var OBSTACLE_PROBABILITY = 0.2;
var MOVE_NOISE = 0.1;
var STEERING_NOISE = 0.1;
var ROBOT_SPEED = 0.5;
var MAX_STEERING_ANGLE = Math.PI/4.0;
var tP = 2.0;
var tI = 0.0001;
var tD = 16.0;
var weightData = 0.1;
var weightSmooth = 0.1;
// Search types
var A_STAR = 0;
var GREEDY = 1;
var BREADTH_FIRST = 2;
var DEPTH_FIRST = 3;
var SEARCH_MODE = A_STAR;
// --------------------------------------------


var BLOCK_SIZE = width/NUM_BLOCKS;
var START = 2;
var GOAL_X = NUM_BLOCKS-1;
var GOAL_Y = NUM_BLOCKS-1;
var GOAL = 3;
var START_COLOR = color(23, 33, 176);
var GOAL_COLOR = color(199, 188, 68);
var FRONTIER_COLOR = color(105, 179, 105);
var EXPLORED_COLOR = color(117, 117, 117, 100);
var PATH_COLOR = color(166, 53, 53);
var SMOOTH_PATH_COLOR = color(53, 68, 166);
var PLAN = 0;
var SMOOTH = 1;
var CALIBRATE = 2;
var NAVIGATE = 3;
var DELTA = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]];


var frontier = [[0, 0, 0, 0]];
var explored = [];
var predecessors = [];
var path = [];
var smoothPath = [];
var mode = PLAN;
var index = 0;
var cte = 0;
var sigma = 0;
angleMode = "radians";

frameRate(60);

// Initialize world
var world = [];
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_BLOCKS; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_BLOCKS; j++) {
        var r = random();
        if (r < OBSTACLE_PROBABILITY) {
            row.push(1);   
        }
        else {
            row.push(0);
        }
    }
    world.push(row);
}
world[0][0] = START;
world[GOAL_Y][GOAL_X] = GOAL;

for (var i = 0; i < NUM_BLOCKS; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_BLOCKS; j++) {
        row.push(false);
    }
    explored.push(row);
}
explored[0][0] = true;
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_BLOCKS; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < NUM_BLOCKS; j++) {
        row.push(null);
    }
    predecessors.push(row);
}

var Robot = function(x, y, size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.orientation = 0;
    this.size = size;
    
    // Thanks to Sebastian Thrun for this code:
    // https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs373/l-48696626/e-48403941/m-48729137
    // My code for this movement can be found at:
    // https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/bicycle-model/5496951953031168
    this.move = function(d, theta) {
        var generator = new Random(millis());
        var moveDistance = (generator.nextGaussian() * MOVE_NOISE) + d;
        var turnAngle = (generator.nextGaussian() * STEERING_NOISE) + theta;
        
        turnAngle = min(turnAngle, MAX_STEERING_ANGLE);
        turnAngle = max(turnAngle, -MAX_STEERING_ANGLE);
        
        var turn = tan(turnAngle)*moveDistance/this.size;
        
        // Approximately straight motion
        if (abs(turn) < 0.001) {
            this.x += moveDistance*cos(this.orientation);
            this.y += moveDistance*sin(this.orientation);
            this.orientation = (this.orientation+turn)%(2.0*Math.PI);
        }
        // Move using the bicyle model
        else {
            var radius = moveDistance/turn;
            var cx = this.x-(sin(this.orientation)*radius);
            var cy = this.y+(cos(this.orientation)*radius);
            this.orientation = (this.orientation+turn)%(2.0*Math.PI);
            this.x = cx + (sin(this.orientation)*radius);
            this.y = cy - (cos(this.orientation)*radius);
        }
    };
    
    this.draw = function() {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(this.x, this.y);
        rotate(this.orientation);
        
        fill(128, 27, 27);
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        rect(-this.size/2, -(this.size*0.75*0.5), this.size, this.size*0.75);
        
        popMatrix();
    };
    
};
var robot;

var addToFrontier = function(node) {
    // Insert the node into the frontier
    // Order by lowest cost
    var i = frontier.length-1;
    if (SEARCH_MODE === A_STAR) {
        while (i > 0 && node[2]+node[3] < frontier[i][2]+frontier[i][3]) {
            i--;   
        }
    }
    else if (SEARCH_MODE === GREEDY) {
        while (i > 0 && node[3] < frontier[i][3]) {
            i--;   
        }
    }
    else if (SEARCH_MODE === BREADTH_FIRST) {
        frontier.push(node);
    }
    else if (SEARCH_MODE === DEPTH_FIRST) {
        frontier.splice(0, 0, node);
    }
    frontier.splice(i+1, 0, node);
};

var distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return sqrt(pow(x1-x2, 2) + pow(y1-y2, 2));
};

var manhattanDistance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2);
};

var drawWorld = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    for (var i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < world[0].length; j++) {
            if (world[i][j] === 1) {
                stroke(0, 0, 0);
                fill(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (world[i][j] === START) {
                fill(START_COLOR);
                stroke(START_COLOR);
            }
            else if (world[i][j] === GOAL) {
                fill(GOAL_COLOR);
                stroke(GOAL_COLOR);
            }
            else {
                fill(255, 255, 255);
                noStroke();
            }
            rect(j*BLOCK_SIZE, i*BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
    }
};

var simulate = function(steps) {
    var error = 0;
    var crosstrackError = 0;
    var r = new Robot(0, 1, BLOCK_SIZE/2);
    var sigma = 0;
    var diff = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < steps*2; i++) {
        // Compute cte
        diff = r.y-crosstrackError;
        crosstrackError = r.y;
        sigma += crosstrackError;
        if (i > steps) {
            error += pow(crosstrackError, 2);
        }
        
        // Update robot
        r.move(ROBOT_SPEED, -tP*crosstrackError - tD*diff - tI*sigma);
    }
    
    return error;
};

draw = function() {
    drawWorld();
    
    // Use A* to find a path to the goal
    if (mode === PLAN) {
        // Draw explored
        fill(EXPLORED_COLOR);
        noStroke();
        for (var i = 0; i < explored.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < explored[0].length; j++) {
                if (explored[i][j]) {
                    rect(j*BLOCK_SIZE, i*BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
                }
            }
        }
        // Draw frontier
        fill(FRONTIER_COLOR);
        noStroke();
        for (var i = 0; i < frontier.length; i++) {
           rect(frontier[i][0]*BLOCK_SIZE, frontier[i][1]*BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        }

        // A*
        if (frontier.length > 0) {
            // Remove a node from the frontier
            var x = frontier[0][0];
            var y = frontier[0][1];
            var cost = frontier[0][2];
            //println(cost + ", " + frontier[0][3]);
            frontier.splice(0, 1);
            
            // Goal check
            if (world[y][x] === GOAL) {
                mode = SMOOTH;
            }
            else {
                // Add all adjacent unexplored nodes
                for (var i = 0; i < DELTA.length; i++) {
                    // If the new position is in the world
                    var x2 = x + DELTA[i][0];
                    var y2 = y + DELTA[i][1];
                    if (x2 >= 0 && x2 < world[0].length && y2 >= 0 && y2 < world.length) {
                        // If the position is unexplored
                        if (!explored[y2][x2] && world[y2][x2] !== 1) {
                            explored[y2][x2] = true;
                            predecessors[y2][x2] = [x, y];
                            addToFrontier([x2, y2, cost+1, dist(x2, y2, GOAL_X, GOAL_Y)]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        else {
            mode = -1;
            println("No possible path to goal.");
        }
    }
    // Smooth the path
    else if (mode === SMOOTH) {
        // Build path
        if (path.length === 0) {
            var x = GOAL_X;
            var y = GOAL_Y;
            path.splice(0, 0, [x, y]);
            smoothPath.splice(0, 0, [x, y]);
            while (x !== 0 || y !== 0) {
                var newX = predecessors[y][x][0];
                var newY = predecessors[y][x][1];
                x = newX;
                y = newY;
                path.splice(0, 0, [x, y]);
                smoothPath.splice(0, 0, [x, y]);
            }
        }
        
        // Draw the original path
        stroke(PATH_COLOR);
        strokeWeight(5);
        for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            point(BLOCK_SIZE*path[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*path[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        strokeWeight(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < path.length-1; i++) {
            line(BLOCK_SIZE*path[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*path[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*path[i+1][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*path[i+1][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        
        // Draw the new path
        stroke(SMOOTH_PATH_COLOR);
        strokeWeight(5);
        for (var i = 0; i < smoothPath.length; i++) {
            point(BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        strokeWeight(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < smoothPath.length-1; i++) {
            line(BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i+1][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2,
            BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i+1][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        
        // Perform gradient descent
        var update;
        var diff = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < smoothPath.length-1; i++) {
            update = [0, 0];
            for (var j = 0; j < smoothPath[0].length; j++) {
                update[j] += weightData * (path[i][j] - smoothPath[i][j]);
                update[j] += weightSmooth * (smoothPath[(i+1)%smoothPath.length][j] + smoothPath[(i-1+smoothPath.length)%smoothPath.length][j] - 2*smoothPath[i][j]);
            }
            // Simulataneous update
            for (var j = 0; j < smoothPath[0].length; j++) {
                smoothPath[i][j] += update[j];
                diff += abs(update[j]);
            }
        }
        if (diff < 0.000001) {
            robot = new Robot(BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE/2);
            mode = NAVIGATE;   
        }
        
    }
    else if (mode === CALIBRATE) {
        var steps = 100;
        var error = simulate(steps);
        var dp = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
        var params = [0, 0, 0];
        if (error/steps > 0.04) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
                params[i] += dp[i];
                var newError = simulate(steps);
                if (newError < error) {
                    error = newError;
                    dp[i] *= 1.1;
                }
                else {
                    params[i] -= 2*dp[i];
                    newError = simulate(steps);
                    if (newError < error) {
                        error = newError;
                        dp[i] *= -1.1;
                    }
                    else {
                        params[i] += dp[i];
                        dp[i] *= 0.9;
                    }
                }
            }
            tP = params[0];
            tD = params[1];
            tI = params[2];
            println(error/steps);
        }
        else {
            println(params);
            tP = params[0];
            tD = params[1];
            tI = params[2];
            mode = NAVIGATE;
        }
    }
    // Use PID control to follow the path
    else if (mode === NAVIGATE) {
        
        // Draw path
        stroke(SMOOTH_PATH_COLOR);
        strokeWeight(5);
        for (var i = 0; i < smoothPath.length; i++) {
            point(BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        strokeWeight(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < smoothPath.length-1; i++) {
            line(BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2, BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i+1][0]+BLOCK_SIZE/2,
            BLOCK_SIZE*smoothPath[i+1][1]+BLOCK_SIZE/2);
        }
        
        // Draw robot
        robot.draw();
        
        // Compute cte
        var diff = -cte;
        var x1 = smoothPath[index][0]*BLOCK_SIZE+BLOCK_SIZE/2;
        var y1 = smoothPath[index][1]*BLOCK_SIZE+BLOCK_SIZE/2;
        var x2 = smoothPath[index+1][0]*BLOCK_SIZE+BLOCK_SIZE/2;
        var y2 = smoothPath[index+1][1]*BLOCK_SIZE+BLOCK_SIZE/2;
        var dx = x2-x1;
        var dy = y2-y1;
        var d = sqrt(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));
        var u = ((robot.x-x1)*dx + (robot.y-y1)*dy)/(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));
        var Px = x1 + d*u*cos(atan2(dy, dx));
        var Py = y1 + d*u*sin(atan2(dy, dx));
        cte = ((robot.y-y1)*dx-(robot.x-x1)*dy)/(pow(dx, 2) + pow(dy, 2));
        sigma += cte;
        diff += cte;
        
        if (u > 1) {
            index++;
            index = min(index, smoothPath.length-2);
        }
        
        // Update robot
        robot.move(ROBOT_SPEED, -tP*cte - tD*diff - tI*sigma);
        //println(index);
    }
    
};
```

but all that happens is that a grey screen shows up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: when I run this guys code on codeHs using the processing library there are no errors but I see nothing but grey as the result. I try the same code on KhanAcademy and have no problems, the code works fine.